# lua json parse variable

Tags: json, parsing, variables, lua

Is possible use a variable to parse a json's path? Like this?

```
json = require('json')
base={magali={pass='melancia'}}

--~ local oo = json.decode( readAll("../json/base.json") )
local oo = base
user = 'magali'
print("oo[" .. oo.magali.pass .. "]") -- work
print("oo[" .. oo.user.pass .. "]") -- does not work! How do this?
```

Error:

```
lua53: example.lua:34: attempt to index a nil value (field 'user')
stack traceback:
    example.lua:34: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

Comment: `oo[user].pass` (assuming you set variable `user = "magali"`)